# Django TDD testing metrics

Tags: django, unit-testing, tdd, bdd

I want to adopt TDD/BDD for my project, as a learning experience, and also because I'm legitimately interested in the practices. [So far, I've been writing code first, and then writing tests, since so far it's a lot of trivial code that's easier to write out first, then add tests for it.  Once I'm finished with work on trivial code, I will move to hopefully writing tests first, and then writing code for it!  But for now... it's not there, or I'm not there, I'm new to it after all!]

I've been using coverage.py in conjunction with django-nose to make sure I always have 100% code coverage (branch coverage I think they call it).

I'm noticing two problems trying to add tests: I'm testing ridiculously unimportant code -- like the unicode() method for my models, that's not used anywhere publicly facing -- just to keep 100% code coverage, and I feel that so much is intertwined with Django, I can't manage to test just -one- unit at a time, but multiple.

Is there a better metric I could use?  When am I testing "too much?" How can I treat my tests more as unit tests, than just regular old sloppy tests?  I'm afraid to just say "well, I'll ignore those," because I'll widen the scope every piece of code I write.

[EDIT] I've seen a guide on TDD for Django, and I liked it-- but it still left me with questions.

Comment: I hope it was my guide!  http://tdd-django-tutorial.com.

Comment: re testing "ridiculously unimportant code" - I really wouldn't worry too much about that.  In general, writing a 2-line test for a 2-line `__unicode__` function really doesn't take that much time.  And there is an upside - if you have a minimal test for `__unicode__`, and indeed everything else, it makes it more likely that you'll extend that test if you ever decide to make that trivial function more complex - it's a stub, or a placeholder, which reduces the psychological threshold for writing future tests...

Comment: Yes it was!  I really enjoyed it, especially that it was updated for 1.4 with LiveServerTestCase -- that made it even more enjoyable (I can't imagine how much more... "fun" selenium was before that).  I guess you have a good point!  If it ever gets more complex, I guess I'll want the test code there already.  I also find myself with hard-to-unit-test code [my functional tests definitely hit it!] (or at least they're not caught with coverage in unit-tests) like signals, or ovverridden methods in a Generic View [get_form() CreateView()].  How do you manage to keep unit tests as units like this?

Comment: mocks usually help, and if you're finding them too hard - might be worth thinking about a different implementation?